# How does Koa help avoid "monkey patching" and how "Hapi" or "Express" don't do the same?

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js, koa

I have hard times understanding why people preach Koa as solving the "monkey patching" problem (whereas one needs to modify prepackaged code).  (see https://www.quora.com/Should-I-learn-Express-js-or-Koa-js-for-node/answer/Yvan-Scher?share=1 or http://blog.onclickinnovations.com/koa-js/).

How is Koa special in that regards? How isn't Hapi or Express the same in that regards?

Comment: You'd better ask a person who made this statement. But since Koa was written from scratch and doesn't have to carry Express baggage (including early Node antipatterns), the code is neater. E.g. the router is decoupled from the framework. You'd have to patch a router to change the behaviour for `app.get` in Express.

Comment: @estus I think the statement is rather in regards of the third-party npm modules the are "required" in the app. Is is somehow easier to monkey-patch third-party modules in Koa?  (edit: maybe I over-read this)

Comment: Depends on a module. Express may require to use more hacks to make things work. I'd suggest to invite the author to participate. Things are very different with Hapi because it doesn't try to make Frankenstein's monster of `http` API, in contrast to Express and Koa. Any way, it has its own flaws, design-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Having done Koa for 2 years, and some express.js recently, I ran into 1 big example of this.

Say you have a controller that emits a response, and you want to intercept that response and do something with it (e.g.: gzip it, or convert it to some other format).

This works easily natively with koa because you can just do something like this:

```
function myMw(ctx, next) {
   await next();
   ctx.response.body = gzip(ctx.response.body);
}
```

The above is a fictional example, but you get the idea.

With express your code for this looks like absolute garbage. Easy to see in the express gzip middleware:

https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/master/index.js

This has to do with the fact that express middlewares provide direct access to the HTTP socket for writing responses (with `send()`).

I'm suspecting this is where this sentiment comes from. Frankly I don't understand why people still use Express. Mostly habitual and the vast amounts of tutorials I reckon. Express *was* great, but it's painful today.

Comment: Alright, thanks for you answer! And where do you think `Hapi` fits in the picture in regards to that sentiment?

Comment: I don't have any Hapi experience, sorry!

Comment: No worries then! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: *Frankly I don't understand why people still use Express* - because they are focused on result. Express ecosystem is extensive. A framework can be astounding itself but if it requires you to reinvent the wheel or investigate things on your own there's nobody who could document them or answer your question, this is a show-stopper.